# ATND gets Response when Xbee Router AT is connected to Computer, no response when on breadboard

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee

I have a Xbee Series 2 in Coordinator AT which is connected to a computer, a Xbee Series 2 in Router AT which is connected to a breadboard and powered by Arduino's +3.3V and GND rails.

**Coordinator AT**

```
atid
2001
atsl
40A74613
atdl
40B19213
```

**Router AT**

```
atid
2001
atsl
40B19213
atdl
40A74613
```

When I use Coolterm to send the command `ATND` from the Coordinator XBee, theres no response from the Router XBee. Connecting pin 13 of the Router Xbee to an LED causes the LED to light up, so I guess the Router Xbee is powered properly.

**`ATND` sent from the Coordinator AT**

```
atnd
0000
0013A200
40A74613

FFFE
00
00
C105
101E
00030000
```

---

However when I also connect the Router Xbee to the computer (so both Xbees are connected to the computer), `ATND` does get a response from the Router XBee.

**`ATND` sent from the Coordinator AT**

```
atnd
0000
0013A200
40A74613

FFFE
00
00
C105
101E
00030000

3626
0013A200
40B19213

FFFE
01
00
C105
101E
00030000
```

How can I troubleshoot this problem?